# FragmentContainerView: Fragment from NavigationGraph does not inflate

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-inflate, android-navigation-graph

So, I was following the Google's Kotlin Fundamental Course and on topic 3.2 (Add Navigation Drawer), creating the XML file where I added a fragment as NavHostFragment, it gave me a warning to replace it with FragmentContainerView which I ignored but my application kept on crashing giving me error that cannot inflate fragment. So, I replaced the fragment to FragmentContainerView. Now my application starts, but it does not inflate the fragment that is set to be the starting fragment in my navigation. It would be great if you guys can help me with it. TIA.

Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
            tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        //val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.navigation)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.myNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        //val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawerLayout)
    }
}
```

Navigation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.kotlinfundamentals.login.LoginFragment"
        android:label="LoginFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment> </navigation>
```

And here is the link to the tutorial I followed:][1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-add-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#9)